# Boost.Spirit.X3 how to prevent token from being parsed by previous rule?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-x3

given this grammar :

```cpp
const auto grammar_def = x3::lit("start")
                        > x3::lit("{")
                        > (*(char_("a-zA-Z0-9\".{}=_~")))
                        > x3::lit("}") > x3::lit(";");
```

the last **x3::lit("}")** is being consumed by **(*(char_("a-zA-Z0-9\".{}=_~")))** since it contains **"}"**
is there way to prevent that ? something like giving **x3::lit("}")** higher priority during parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write a custom parser that works like kleene star but can backtrack and also takes a second parser that must match as well. Something like this should work.

```
        template <class Left, class Right>
        struct backtracking : binary_parser<Left, Right, backtracking<Left, Right>>
        {
            using base = binary_parser<Left, Right, backtracking<Left, Right>>;
            backtracking(Left const& left, Right const& right)
                :  base(left, right)
            {
            }

            template<typename It, typename Ctx, typename Other>
            bool parse(It& f, It l, Ctx const& ctx, Other const& other, unused_type) const
            {
                auto end_it = l;
                while (end_it != f) {
                    auto save = f;
                    if (this->left.parse(f, end_it, ctx, other, unused)) {
                        if (this->right.parse(f, l, ctx, other, unused))
                            return true;
                    }
                    f = save;
                    --end_it;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

const auto grammar_def = x3::lit("start")
                        > x3::lit("{")
                        > backtracking(
                             *(char_("a-zA-Z0-9\".{}=_~")), lit("}") >> lit(";"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found was to disallow the kleene star from matching a `'}'` if a `;` came after.

```
const auto grammar_def = x3::lit("start")
                        > x3::lit("{")
                        > *(char_("a-zA-Z0-9\".{}=_~") >> !lit(';'))
                        > x3::lit("}") > x3::lit(";");
```

Comment: it works for this case, but I'm looking for something more generic, e.g : assuming ";" is also in the expression .